# Unable to execute system query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute this query

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests;
```

but I am getting error..

> Table 'sys.dm_exec_requests' doesn't exist

Any solution of this?

Comment: You are running this query on mysql or ms sql?

Comment: i am running this on mysql !

Comment: @Mayankkumar . . . Then don't use SQL Server functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sys.dm_exec_requests` DMV requires at least SQL Server 2008 or later. The user executing the request also requires the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission.

REF: [sys.dm_exec_requests (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)